# Accessing Lucene index at a lower level

Tags: indexing, lucene, information-retrieval

Let's say I have a token t = "string1" and I want to find all the documents where this token appears, from a lucene index. One way is to make a query using this token and get the Hits. But let's way we have many tokens like this. Issuing one query for each token is definitely not efficient. So, is there a way to perform the following task efficiently, maybe by accessing the index at a much lower level to avoid unnecessary overhead -

Given n tokens (string like) find one list for each token which contains the list of documentID where that token appears ?

The index can be huge - 17M files and number of tokens to be searched can be ~500.

Comment: Are you using elasticsearch but want to access Lucene directly? Why not just use something like the terms filter?

Comment: No I am not using elastic search. But I have known that elastic search people know a lot about lucene, that's why added the tag.

Comment: What you are describing is just a search.  Searching with a `TermQuery` gets all the document ids for documents that contain that term.  Might save a bit on performance with a `ConstantScoreQuery`.  You are looking for separate result sets, so running the queries separately definitely does make sense.  You can combine them all in a `BooleanQuery` if you like, but you obviously won't get separate result sets that way.  It sounds a like you are asking if there is some secret *better, faster* index search function hidden away somewhere in the API, to which I'd say: No (or at least, i doubt it)...

Comment: I do am looking for a faster way. In my use case there can be roughly 15-17M documents in the index and the query can have number of terms upto 500, which can take long time to run. Is there a way to find the partition of the index where a particular term is and then access that partition to get access to the data structure that holds the documentIds for the terms ?